# Can't change language in vim 7.3.35

Tags: vim

I use (g)vim from default Ubuntu repo. Before updating to 7.3 everything was working. After updating to 7.3 I just can't change vim's language. First I checked if the locale I want to set is available on my system.

```
~ $ locale -a | grep en_US
en_US.utf8
```

Now in vim I typed many variations of `language` command like:

```
:language en_US.utf8
:lan mes en_US.utf8
```

but it didn't worked and I still have vim in the default language of my system. And yes, I have `language en_US.utf8` in my vimrc. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried just 'en_US' without the encoding?

Comment: Try also calling vim with the command "LANG='en_US' vim"

Comment: When you first open vim, type `:language`. What is your output?

Answer (score 5):

Just rename "lang" dir in vim program directory to "lang.backup" and everything will be back in english language.

Comment: Radical, but effective !

Answer (score 2):

Try the following command:

```
:language US
```